# Mysql Left Join Force Group By

Tags: mysql, database

I have notice that when I use a left join to another table, My data duplicates itself and I don't have more option than make a group by so that I could have the correct rows.

```
SELECT * from tbla a left join tblb b on a.id=b.id_a
group by a.id
```

Are there a way to make a left join returning correct rows with no duplicate?

Comment: Hi there, welcome to SO. Understand that this is only possible because you are using MySQL that does not follow the ANSI pattern (entirelly). a `select *` with a group by would give you an error in any other database. To answer you properly you would have to show us some data sample so we can se why it is getting you duplicated lines. It alwasy about the joins, when you join a table that has a registry A with another table that references A twice you will have a duplicate this is the normal behavior.

Comment: @JorgeCampos it's not just mysql that supports this group by functionality, sybase and teradata are also known for this feature.

Comment: @Shadow Good to know that! Thanks, Although I would not call it feature, I would call BAD DESIGN since there is an unified pattern to define sql language. But that is a big discussion right :)

Comment: @JorgeCampos this feature has its uses, if the person understands under what circumstances to use it. The problem with mysql is that too many beginners use mysql without proper sql knowledge any understanding of this feature.

Comment: @Shadow Although I agree that it has its uses, it is always possible to do whatever it do with proper sql pattern that's the why I called it a bad desing. It only facilitates the job at the cost of missguiding newcomers as you said

Answer (score 0):

depend on your data, you are probably having duplicated id on tablea so you are creating duplicates.

without know your data you have two options

```
SELECT *
FROM 
     (
      SELECT DISTINCT <tablA_fields> 
      from tbla a 
     ) as A
left join      (
      SELECT DISTINCT <tablB_fields> 
      from tblb b
     ) as B
tblb b on A.id = B.id_a
```

Second option use `group by` instead on each sub select.